# arduino python interface with multiple variables

Tags: python, interface, arduino

I want to bring 3 sensor variables that change all the time to my python interface.

I am trying with this test code, it does not work, what am I doing wrong?

Arduino:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print(random(1,3)); 
  Serial.print(random(3,5));
  Serial.print(random(5,7)); 
}
```

Python:

```
canvas.create_text(190, 150, text=ser.readline(1), fill="gray", font="Helvetica 45 bold",tag="T1")
```

How can I get multiple variables updating all the time? right now I am just getting the first one, and it is not updating

Comment: where are you calling `update`?

Comment: Thank you, I missed that. but when I put update() my code crash. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using the `readline` function to read just one byte? Since you want multiple values, separate the variables with (for instance) a space, then use `readline` to store them all and `split` to separate them:

PS: note that the last one is actually a `println`

Arduino:

```
void loop() {
  Serial.print(random(1,3));
  Serial.print(" "); 
  Serial.print(random(3,5));
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(random(5,7)); 
}
```

Python:

```
allitems=ser.readline()
separateditems=allitems.split();
canvas.create_text(190, 150, " - ".join(separateditems), fill="gray", font="Helvetica 45 bold",tag="T1")
```

In this example I put the items in the `separateditems` list (so `separateditems[0]` is equal to `random(1,3)`, `separateditems[1]` is equal to `random(3,5)` and `separateditems[2]` is equal to `random(5,7)`). Then I joined them to display "random(1,3) - random(3,5) - random(5,7)". Anyway you can do whatever you want with the collected data.

Then I HIGHLY suggest you to put a delay inside the `loop`, to avoid sending too many data. I suggest putting a `delay(100);` at the end or, if you need to do other things while waiting, see the "Bounce without delay" example.