# Update value all the time in python interface (Arduino)

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, arduino

This is the code I created for an arduino interface using python, I want the 3 variables to change all the time in my python interface. But they are not updating, it is just taking the fist values, I would like the screen to be able to update the values by itself.

How can I do it?

Arduino

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
}

void loop() {
  //Serial.print(3); 
  Serial.print(random(1,3));
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(random(3, 6));
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(random(7,9));
  Serial.print(" ");
  delay(200);
}
```

Python

```
import serial
import time
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/cu.usbmodem1411", 9600, timeout=1)
flagCharacter = 'k'

canvas = Canvas(root, width=1024, height=574)
canvas.pack()

photo = PhotoImage(file= r"rsz_fiori.gif")
label=Label(root, image=photo)
photo = PhotoImage(file= r"rsz_fiori.gif")
canvas.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor='nw')

def sensores(planeado, producido, alertas):
    canvas.create_text(190, 150, text=planeado, fill="gray", font="Helvetica 45 bold",tag="T1")
    canvas.create_text(333, 150, text=producido, fill="gray", font="Helvetica 45 bold",tag="T2")
    canvas.create_text(463, 150, text=alertas, fill="gray", font="Helvetica 45 bold",tag="T3")

while True:
    ser.write(flagCharacter)
    allitems=ser.readline(6)
    x, y, z = allitems.split()
    sensores(x, y, z)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There is just one main difference between the answer I gave you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33380721/arduino-python-interface-with-multiple-variables/33386734#33386734) and your new code, and that will cause you endless pains. You are sending six chars and reading six chars, but what happens when you open the pthon program when the arduino is sending the second data? Simple: you will get misaligned data. The right way to do this is to use something to show the program the beginning or the end of the packet

Comment: Now, like I told you in the other question, since you are using `readline` why don't you want to use new lines? So substitute `Serial.print(random(7,9));Serial.print(" ");` with `Serial.println(random(7,9));` and `allitems=ser.readline(6)` with `allitems=ser.readline()`. And you will save yourself a lot of troubles ;) And by the way, if you are sending a data every 200ms you can update the UI every 200ms (or even better 100ms); this way you will see every data. The fastest speed, however, sould be 100ms: under this value you won't be able to read the data ;)

Comment: @frarugi87 How can I get the 3 values, if I do it the way you say?    I would have:
x,y,z=ser.readline()
sensores(x, y, z)    
I am just getting the first variable

Comment: I mean, I am getting the 3 variables in just my first canvas.create text

Comment: Wait, now you are reading six chars and then splitting them. Do the same! I mean, instead of `allitems=ser.readline(6)` and `x, y, z = allitems.split()` you just have to do `allitems=ser.readline()` and `x, y, z = allitems.split()`

Comment: @frarugi87 got it. thank you.

Comment: @frarugi87 I am facing a new issue, I am  not able to send the data from the sensors, I dont understand why, I works when sending data from an arduino random function.   I posted the question yesterday, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33471037/cannot-update-sensor-data-in-python-tkinter-from-my-arduino-sensors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `mainloop` from an infinite loop -- that doesn't work the way you think it does.

The proper way to do something "all the time" is to create a function that updates everything once, and then call that function via `after`. It would look something like this:

```
def do_update():
    ser.write(flagCharacter)
    allitems=ser.readline(6)
    x, y, z = allitems.split()
    sensores(x, y, z)
    root.after(1000, do_update)
```

Once you call `do_update` once (and assuming `mainloop` is running) it will cause itself to be run once every 1000ms (1 second). Note that this only works if the call to `ser.readline(6)` doesn't block, and doesn't take more than a few hundred milliseconds.

You'll want to modify `sensores` -- it keeps writing new text items on top of the old. You should either delete the old values, or simply reconfigure them with new values.