# Cannot update sensor data in Python (Tkinter) from my arduino sensors

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, arduino

I am learning about interfaces on Python Tkinter. I was testing before sending random numbers from my arduino to my Python interface, It worked (It updates all the time), so I thought it was going to work when sending data from a sensor, but it did not.

So, this is a test code, if I am pressing the button, I would have to send 3 variables with the number 1, and if I am not, I will get 2 variables with the number 2 and one random variable.

So, I never get the values that I should get when pressing the button. I am always getting: random number, 2 and 2.

Arduino:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin (9600);
  pinMode(i_presion, INPUT);
}

void loop() 
{
 if(digitalRead(i_presion) == HIGH ) 
  { 
  Serial.print(1);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(1);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(1);
  Serial.print(" "); 
  }
 else 
 { 
  Serial.print(random(3,8));
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(2);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.print(2);
  Serial.print(" "); 
  }
}
```

Python:

```
import serial
import time
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
ser = serial.Serial("/dev/cu.usbmodem1411", 9600, timeout=1)

flagCharacter = 'k'

canvas = Canvas(root, width=1920, height=1080)
canvas.pack()

photo = PhotoImage(file= r"ANDREA-FIORI2.gif")
label=Label(root, image=photo)
photo = PhotoImage(file= r"ANDREA-FIORI2.gif")
canvas.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand='yes')
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo, anchor='nw')



def sensores(planeado, producido, alertas):

    canvas.create_text(390, 430, text=planeado, fill="gray", font="Helvetica 100 bold",tag="T1")
    canvas.create_text(650, 430, text=producido, fill="gray", font="Helvetica 100 bold",tag="T2")
    canvas.create_text(900, 430, text=alertas, fill="gray", font="Helvetica 100 bold",tag="T3")

    #root.after(1000,sensores)

def borrar():
    canvas.delete("T1")
    canvas.delete("T2")
    canvas.delete("T3")

def do_update():
    ser.write(flagCharacter)
    borrar()
    allitems=ser.readline(6)
    x, y, z = allitems.split()
    sensores(x, y, z)
    root.after(1000, do_update)

do_update()
root.mainloop()
```

Any ideas of why it is updating the function random, and not information from my sensors?

Comment: have you done any debugging, such as putting in a print statement in `sensores` to verify it is getting the values you think it should be getting?

Comment: @BryanOakley I just saw the arduino output on the serial window and used print x,y,z after  allitems=ser.readline(6). And they are getting the right values. But it is not updating the values on the canvas.create_text

Comment: @BryanOakley I found it something interesting, it just transmit the right information when the arduino serial window is open. 
For me it does not make any sense, but works. Do you have any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that if you change this

```
pinMode(i_presion, INPUT);
```

Into this

```
pinMode(i_presion, INPUT_PULLUP);
```

It will start working....

The reason is that you are not pulling up the pin when the button is not pressed.

Or, at least, this is the most common reason for the...

> I never get the values that I should get when pressing the button. I am always getting: random number, 2 and 2

...problem.

Comment: But the message I am sending depends of the sensor, but it is not the information of the sensor.

Comment: Sorry but WHAT is "the sensor"? In your code I can only see a button and some data that you forced to be 1 or 2 and random. There is no sensor.